# SplitViewcontroller programmatically hide master view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

There are a few questions here on stackoverflow that deal with this, but none of the answers seem to work for me. I am trying to hide the masterview of a split view controller from a button on the detail view. The delegate of the split view is the app delegate itself. It works when I manually rotate the device, but not before that. How can I make the master view disappear/appear?
Below is my code, based upon answers here on stack overflow (I have tried a bunch of stuff)

```
[self.splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.splitViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.splitViewController.view reloadInputViews];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = nil;
    self.splitViewController.delegate=self;
    [self.splitViewController reloadInputViews];
    [self.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication    sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no ways to hide the master view programically as far as I know, but Matt Gammel has created a custom split view controller that allows lots of monuplation which has a costum built in method toggle the split view visible and hide it. Take a look at project and see if that helps you out. The appearance of the views are mimicking the split view controller so as far as appearance is concerned you should be fine. Anyway here is the direct link to the github project.

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that would be the case. I am aware of that link, but seems to be overkill for something that should be quite straightforward to do.